# Auto open drawable after start app android

Tags: java, android

I want Auto open drawable after start app android

used library https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

this code from Main Activity
If it possible
if possible
And the second question is, can I open the menu on all activities after the swipe to the right? Only the back button now works

```
drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
        .withActivity(this)
        .withToolbar(mToolbar)
        .withSelectedItem(1)
        .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
        .addDrawerItems(
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName(R.string.Home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.News).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_newspaper),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3).withName("About").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question_circle),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4).withName("Open Source").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_github_square),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(5).withName("Rate on Google Play").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_thumbs_up)
        )
        .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
        .build();
drawer.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                return true;
            case 2:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                drawer.setSelection(1);
                startActivity(new Intent(context, NewsListActivity.class));
                return true;
            case 3:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                drawer.setSelection(1);
                startActivity(new Intent(context, AboutTheDevActivity.class));
                return true;
            case 4:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                drawer.setSelection(1);
                libsBuilder.start(context);
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to refactor your application to single activity structure. This will help to solve both of your problems.

- You may just open the drawer in activity `onCreate` method. It is called when activity created, with single activity - when app started.
- Save that drawer was opened to instance state if you need more accuracy here and don't want the drawer to be opened on activity recreation events (states when system decides to destroy your activity to release memory)
- use fragments for showing app screens
- open drawer in this single activity and manage toolbar from activity so it could be opened on every screen

Single activity is the way [google recommends](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1) to structure apps.